# Cannot Load '....' from assembly '...' when using services.AddKendo() in dotnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, .net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc

as the title says.

When i use `services.AddKendo()` in `Startup.cs` my program break and show error like this:

`TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.`

Here the stack trace:

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddKendo(IServiceCollection services)
   at Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Path\Startup.cs:line 53
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()`

Why is this happening? and what is the solution?

I already tried to use that in dotnet core 1.0 also show the same error.

I'm using NuGet Package Kendo.Mvc v2016.2.616

Thanks before for your help

Comment: Is there an inner Exception? Usually those errors are decoys for something else, like an IO Exception trying to load a non-existing DLL. Maybe you have a binding redirecting to an old version of the DLL? I would also try closing Visual Studio -> Deleting temporary files at '%temp%' => open VS again => Clean solution & Rebuild

Comment: There are some setup steps here https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-for-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up versions. i.e. using a newer version of ASP.NET Core i.e 2.1) with an library (or referenced project) with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInject` 1.1 for example